# Reverse engineering tool for Java (Android) Class Diagrams

Tags: java, android, uml, reverse-engineering

I've tried some tools for generate automatically class diagrams from the java source code in Android but none fit my needs. I'd like the following features:

- Create class diagrams from java classes (ignoring the Android's core classes)
- Allow to manually edit the generated diagramas without having to change the code
- Woking both in Windows and Unix (preferable if an Eclipse plugin)
- Do his best if i want to update a diagram edited (and iconsistent with the code) updating the new values and keeping the custom modifications while possible
- Free or affordable for a single user.

Do you know any tool with those features? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [bouml](http://www.bouml.fr), one of the very few tools able to reverse the complete sources of Java (13000 classes !)